When I use mat-tooltip inside mat-icon element in angular material 18 it shows Icon text instead of icon shape
As I mentioned in the title, I'm stuck in a problem with <mat-icon> element when I add matTooltip inside it.
here is my .html tags :
<mat-icon [matTooltip]="element[allColumnsList[this.Verifier_Place].title]">verified</mat-icon>

I also imported MatTooltipModule and CommonModule in the .ts file.
In the result tooltip worked properly but icon just shows icon text instead of icon shape.
Is this a bug?

You have to add the fonts for it to work, maybe you missed that.
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

Material Icons Demo

I don't think so. Without using mat-tooltip I have no problem and the icon shows the true shape.

@BlueMoon Please replicate it stackblitz and share back on the question!

It works on stackblitz but it didn't on my PC. You need to know that for some reasons I prefered to use angular material offline. So I use material icons offline with npm install material-icons@latest command. May be it is a bug. Everything seams to be correct.

@BlueMoon if you share GitHub repo I will check it

@BlueMoon This is a working stackblitz for local material icons
